# Prevent orientation sensor using portrait as default

Tags: android, android-view, android-orientation

I'm using `orientation="sensor"` in my `Activity`. If I start my app in portrait everything works, if I latter change my orientation everything works too (being in portrait or landscape) but if I start my app with my device in landscape, instead of my `Activity` being launched in landscape (like when it does if `orientation="landscape"`) it first starts in portrait and then changes to landscape.
I want to avoid that, I want to have `orientation="sensor"`, but with the Activity launching in portrait if the device is in portrait or in landscape if the device is in landscape.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.